# Google maps API and directions service - definition of a request

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have implemented google maps API with my own API key for a website that I am building. I am aware of the 25000 limit for the map API and the 2500 limit for the directions API. I want to know:

1) what exactly constitutes as a "view"? Is it a single load of the map using my key?

2) if a user zooms in different places in the map and use different zoom levels and other options available in that map, will each one of them constitute as separate views?

3) when using the directions service, I have multiple route directions showing for a single user. Will each single view of a route direction constitute a separate use of the directions service?
Any help is appreciated.

*PS:I understand this question has no coding, but since it is directly related to programming I could not think of any other stackexchange site to ask this. If you can specify, I'll be happy to move the question.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=en#usage_mapload),

**Answers to 1) & 2):**

- A single map load occurs when a map is displayed using the Google Maps JavaScript API when loaded by a web page or application;
- A Street View panorama is displayed using the Google Maps JavaScript API by a web page or application that has not also displayed a map;
- A single request is made for a map image from the Google Static Maps API;
- A single request is made for a panorama image from the Google Street View Image API.

**Answer to 3:** (According to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-limits))

- 2,500 free directions requests per day. Even if you use one map, multiple requests will count.